# How to replace css class name partially in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Let's say I have this html element

```html
<div class="progress-bar w-90"></div>
```

and I want to replace `90` with an object from vue. I tried below but syntax

```html
<div :class="progress-bar w-{{ progress.value }}"></div>
```

Comment: you can try this ```<div :class="`progress-bar w-${progress.value}`"></div>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `{{ }}` in attribute/props, better to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as below.

```html
<div :class="`progress-bar w-${progress.value}`"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve text-binding in this way

```html
<div :class="'progress-bar w-'+progress.value"></div>
```

Comment: @Steve - Great! If it works for you and you are happy - then in general you would accept the answer. This will not only help other people with the same issue but it will also mean people are more likely to help you in the future with any other issues you have. Thankyou